# How do I install an Nvidia driver in VirtualBox?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox

I am trying to install the NVIDIA driver on in an Ubuntu guest running on a Windows host (to install the GPU-supported tensorflow). Is it possible to do this?

I am using NVIDIA GeForce 849M.

I downloaded the driver from NVIDIA and installed it with:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo init 3
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-364.69.run
```

Then I get and warning like the following:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the
>   384.69 NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system.   For further details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS
>   CHIPS in the README available on the Linux driver download page at
>   www.nvidia.com.
>
> -> License accepted.
>
> -> Installing NVIDIA driver version 384.69.
>
> -> Running distribution scripts    executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
>
> -> done.
>
> -> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue? (Answer: Abort installation)
>
> ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
>   '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
>   on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
>   driver download page at www.nvidia.com.

Comment: **Do not install Nvidia drivers in a VM** unless when having two cards and using KVM. The default and typical Virtualbox VM uses virtualized hardware and not the Nvidia directly.

Comment: your host-OS & will see any 'guest' OS trying to access hardware directly as malware/illegal/naughty....   it'll only work if the host-OS (windows in your case) which means its insecure or security is turned off; and its a warning that your host-OS needs securing!

Comment: Why was this down voted? IMO this is an important issues that many should be aware of.

Comment: @MichaelBay and guiverc please post those as answers to the question.

Comment: @George No need because this is just a dupe.